# Images not loading in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load the site in an android app web view.

The site loads without the images ,all the images from the site are not loaded what could be the problem.

The code for onCreate is shown below.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    String url = getResources().getString(R.string.web_url);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    web.loadUrl(url);
}
```

One more note, when i set javascript to false using  web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false); the images load giving a warning that javascript should be enabled to run the site properly.

This site is protected with CloudFlare ,could this be the reason images are not loaded in the android web view ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add

```
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

This should work. Keep the rest as is.

Although a caveat, I don't think its recommended to enable this by default, its disabled by default. The setting allows a website to store data and reuse it. So the images are not being loaded, because this site wasn't allowed to store them on your device. This opens up a can of security concerns.

Comment: Hi With this method the website itself doesn't load

Comment: Hi Thanks a lott ! ! This worked fine . What is the reason that using this worked and not with the earlier case ?

Comment: Hi Should i go with this option ?? There is no harm in using this option if it is then what is an alternative to this ?

Comment: I think for the website you mentioned, this is what works, I'm not sure of a workaround.

Answer (score 16):

Just use this line of code. I think your problem will be solved.

```
     webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
     webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```

You may need this one as well, if you are lazy-loading content:

```
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: if possible, you can also add small description to properties.

Answer (score 8):

Just this will suffice

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```

Comment: This was enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem in **Android 9.0**. The images in the site's html were using **http** instead of **https**.
Then I changed all the http with https and everything worked!
It was very easy to change the http to https using a sql query in mySql.

I am giving the query if it helps anyone!

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = replace(column_name, '<img src="http://', '<img src="https://')
```

Comment: This guy is the true hero. In my case I updated my serializer on the server to re-write http:// urls to https://, but yeah, this was causing issues in my app.

Comment: But what if I have a http server on the local network?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the issue might be your webview client.
Use this instead:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
                Toast.makeText(FundCardWeb.this, "Page Load Error" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi this gives a warning that javascript must be enabled and if i enable javascript the images do not load

Answer (score 2):

for me the combination of adding those did it:

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```

I don't like adding unneccesery cod when so I didn't use:

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue. In the web view, the Image with the http URL was not loading in my app. The following solution fixed my issue,

```
webview.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```

But in Android 9, the above solution has thrown the issue sometimes, in such case  add the following line in the manifest file.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

**My problem was just one image, not loading in webview. I just add this two thing**

In Manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

In java oncreate() just add

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
         mywebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add all the comments here til the image shows up, hahaha

android:usesClearTextTraffic="true"

work for the final try, maybe it depends on what type of image the website is using, just add all the syntaxes of all their answers here til the image shows up

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).